# Getting the filename of a pasted picture with VBA in Word 2010

Tags: vba, ms-word

In Windows 7 the .alternativeText property contained the original filename of a dropped picture into a Word document. Now in Windows 8.1 (still using Office 2010) the alternativeText property is blank. Can anyone think of a way to get that original filename?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Drag/Drop doesn't set alternativeText, but Copy/Paste does. So I just have to make sure that the end user knows to do copy/paste instead.